# Max Sum Subsequence with Threshold

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, recursion, dynamic-programming

Given an array of Integers find the Max Sum of Subsequence which is less than or equal to given Threshold.

Constrants:
Max size of Array is 10^5
Max size if element in array is 10^9
Threshold is in range of 1 to 10^9

e.g.
Input:
1 2 4 5
10

Output:
10

In above example array is [ 1, 2, 4, 5 ] and threshold is 10. Max sum subsequence is 10 formed by (1, 4, 5)

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class MaxSumSubsequenceWithThreshold {

    class Solution {
        int[] A;
        int threshold;
        Integer[][] dp;
        Solution(int[] A, int threshold) {
            this.A = A; this.threshold = threshold;
            dp = new Integer[A.length][threshold + 1];
        }

        int sum(int pos, int threshold) {
            if (threshold <= 0) return 0;
            if (threshold - A[pos] < 0) return dp[pos][threshold] = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
            if (dp[pos][threshold] != null) return dp[pos][threshold];
            int sum = 0;
            int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
            for (int i = pos + 1; i < A.length; i++) {
                sum = sum(i, threshold - A[pos]);
                max = Math.max(max, sum);
            }
            return dp[pos][threshold] = max == Integer.MIN_VALUE ? A[pos] : max + A[pos];
        }

        int solve() {
            Arrays.sort(A);
            int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
            for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
                dp[i][threshold] = sum(i, threshold);
                max = Math.max(max, dp[i][threshold]);
            }
            return max;
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] A = InputUtils.nextIntLine();
        int threshold = InputUtils.nextInt();
        System.out.println(
                new MaxSumSubsequenceWithThreshold().new Solution(A, threshold).solve()
        );
    }

}
```

Need help in verifying if this solution is correct.

Any better solution ?

Comment: For better solution, don't use recursion.

Comment: Is there a limit to the threshold, e.g. `1 <= threshold <= 100` or some such? How many values can there be?

Comment: Added threshold range in description.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For better performance, I would only loop through the values once, and would keep track of all previous sums in a `TreeSet`.

Being a `Set` automatically eliminates duplicate sums. E.g. if input is `[1, 3, 4, 7]`, then by the time we process 7, the sums previously seen will be `[1, 3, 4, 1+3, 1+4, 3+4, 1+3+4] = [1, 3, 4, 4, 5, 7, 8] = [1, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8]`, where the duplicate sum `4` has been eliminated. Prevents redundant processing.

We should stop looking if we find a sum equal to `threshold`. This is known as *short-circuting*. No need to keep looking if we found the max possible sum already. E.g. if `threshold = 8`, we would skip the processing of the `7` value, since we already found a sum equal to `threshold`, i.e. `1+3+4 = 8`.

Being a `SortedSet` allows us to find a subset that can be added to the current value we're processing. E.g. if `threshold = 10`, when we process `7` we look for `3` for potential short-circuit, then only need to consider previous sums in range `1`-`2`, so we can call `subSet(1, 3)` to get those.

Although not explicitly stated in the question, we would consider the empty sub-sequence valid, which means that `0` is a valid result, if we otherwise don't find a solution. Also, while not explicitly stated, we will assume that values cannot be negative. Whether values can exceed `threshold` doesn't matter much, since that's easy to guard against.

With the above logic we wouldn't add sums that exceed `threshold`. E.g. if `threshold = 6`, the above set would contain `[1, 3, 4, 5]`, when we are done. We can then call `last()` to find the max sum.

Here is the code for all of that:

```java
static int maxSum(int threshold, int... values) {
    TreeSet<Integer> sums = new TreeSet<>();
    for (int value : values) {
        if (value == threshold)
            return threshold; // short-circuit
        if (value < threshold) {
            if (sums.contains(threshold - value))
                return threshold; // short-circuit
            for (int prevSum : sums.subSet(1, threshold - value).toArray(new Integer[0]))
                sums.add(prevSum + value);
            sums.add(value);
        }
    }
    return (sums.isEmpty() ? 0 : sums.last().intValue());
}
```

<sup>*Note: We can't add to `sums` while iterating the subset, so we need a copy of the subset. `toArray()` is the fastest way to get such a copy.*</sup>

*Tests*

```java
System.out.println(maxSum(10, 1,2,4,5));
System.out.println(maxSum(8, 1,3,4,7));
System.out.println(maxSum(10, 1,3,4,7));
System.out.println(maxSum(6, 1,3,4,7));
System.out.println(maxSum(3, 5,7,9));
```

*Output*

```
10
8
10
5
0
```